# On Mac how to start a spark-shell in same environment as the environment running in an Intellij project?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, intellij-idea

I am working on a spark project using scala and maven, and some time I feel it would be very helpful if I can ran the project in an interactive mode.

My question if it is possible (and how) to bring up a spark environment in terminal that same as the environment running in a IntelliJ project? 
Or even better (if it is possible) -- start a PERL environment, under IntelliJ debug model, during code ceased running at a break point. So we can continue play with all variables and instances created so far.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, though not very straightforward. I first build Fat jar using sbt assembly plugin (https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) and then use a debug configuration like the one below to start it in debugger. Note that org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit is used as a main class, not your application main class. You app main class is specified in the --class parameter instead.

It is a bit tedious to have to create app jar file before starting each debug session (if sources were changed). I couldn't get SparkSubmit to work with the compiled by IntelliJ class files directly. I'd be happy to hear about alternative ways of doing this.

```
*Main class:*
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit

*VM Options:*

-cp <SPARK_DIR>/conf/:<SPARK_DIR>/jars/* -Xmx6g -Dorg.xerial.snappy.lib.name=libsnappyjava.jnilib -Dorg.xerial.snappy.tempdir=/tmp

*Program arguments:*

--master
local[*]
--class
com.example.YourSparkApp

<PROJECT_DIR>/target/scala-2.11/YourSparkAppFat.jar
<APP_ARGS>
```

If you don't care much about initialization or can insert a loop in the code where the app waits for a keystroke or any other kind of signal before continuing, then you can start you app as usual and simply attach IntelliJ to the app process (Run > Attach to Local Process...).

Comment: thank youk, Denis! It is more way complicated than I thought, but I will give it try. Thanks in advance!